# "А ларчик просто открывался" - значение

Tags: фразеология

*Написал эту фразу в другой теме - и вспомнилась детская непонятка.
Правильно ли мы ее, эту фразу, понимаем? Не как идиому, а в исходном состоянии.*

Короче, какие есть мнения, почему Крылов оставил читающих в неведении о способе открытия ларчика?

Дабы избежать ненужного цитирования в ответах.

ЛАРЧИК
Случается не редко нам
И труд и мудрость видеть там,
Где стоит только догадаться
За дело просто взяться.
К кому-то принесли от мастера Ларец.
Отделкой, чистотой Ларец в глаза кидался;
Ну, всякий Ларчиком прекрасным любовался.
Вот входит в комнату механики мудрец.
Взглянув на Ларчик, он сказал: "Ларец с секретом,
Так, он и без замка;
А я берусь открыть; да, да, уверен в этом;
Не смейтесь так исподтишка!
Я отыщу секрет и Ларчик вам открою:
В механике и я чего-нибудь да стою".
Вот за Ларец принялся он:
Вертит его со всех сторон
И голову свою ломает;
То гвоздик, то другой, то скобку пожимает.
Тут, глядя на него, иной
Качает головой;
Те шепчутся, а те смеются меж собой.
В ушах лишь только отдается:
"Не тут, не так, не там!" Механик пуще рвется.
Потел, потел; но, наконец, устал,
От Ларчика отстал
И, как открыть его, никак не догадался:
А Ларчик просто открывался. 
*
(С) И. А. Крылов

Comment: Крылов, за давностью смерти, не является обладателем авторских прав на данное произведение, и значок копирайта излишен.

Comment: Вы на редкость проницательны. )))
Вся фишка в том, что Вы, видимо, недавно узнали про Интернет. Здесь свои правила и значок (С) чаще обозначает авторство, а не компирайты. С этим можно не соглашаться, но по факту - так.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему Крылов оставил в неведении? Не знаю, видимо, не захотел объяснять очевидное - ларец "без замка", открывается путём поднятия крышки.

> Случается не редко нам
> И труд и мудрость видеть там,
> Где стоит только догадаться
> За дело просто взяться

Comment: Хорошо, как Вы понимаете фразу в заголовке?  
Двусмысленности не видите?

Comment: Не вижу смысла тут искать двусмысленность. "Просто" - значит обычным, примитивным образом, без секретов. Самый простой способ открытия ларца, поднять крышку, блистает своим отсутствием, следовательно имеется в виду именно он.

Все остальные версии или требуют каких-то фактов помимо текста басни (разъяснения автора, эта же басня на других языках), или изрядной доли домысливания на ровном месте.

Comment: >Не вижу смысла тут искать двусмысленность.  
  
Н-да... Двусмысленности не ищут, они сами возникают. )))   
Столько слов - и все ради того чтобы доказать непонятно что.
Ладно, специально для тех, кто читает басни на других языках.

Замените "Ларчик" на "задача", "открывался" на "решался". 
***Задача просто решается.*** 
Больше я Вам подсказывать не буду.

Comment: Если ударение на **просто**, то ларчик открывался самым простым способом, т.е. раз "замка нет", то открыванием крышки.

Если ударение, на **открывался**, то ларчик, был без запора, и открывался элементарным поднятием крышки.

Следовательно, как ни читай результат один и тот же, а потому и двусмысленности здесь тоже нет. Как читал басню Крылов мы не узнаем никогда, соответственно способ чтения данной строчки индивидуальный выбор чтеца.

Answer (score 4):

Но мне все же кажется, - это наречие  - обстоятельство образа действия. В контексте говорится как мастер пытался,мучался открыть ларчик,но не мог.А на самом деле ларчик ПРОСТО(каким образом?)(а не всего лишь) открывался,без проблем,легко; стоило лишь поднять крышку.

Вот что ответила Грамма. Как-то забыл я написать ответ.
***Ответ Граммы.ру***

> В басне Крылова " А ларчик просто открывался" слово "просто", по общепринятому мнению, является наречием (ларчик открывался как? - просто, легко, без труда). Однако есть и другие мнения (на наш взгляд, спекулятивные, уж простите за резкость), согласно которым слово "просто" в этой строке является частицей в значении "всего лишь".

Comment: Это выглядело бы вполне логичным. Как минимум - версия имеет право на существование. А чем является просто в первом случае? В четвертой строчке?

Comment: Похоже, что наречие. Взяться за дело КАК? просто, без затей. По контрасту со словом МУДРОСТЬ.

Comment: >Похоже, что наречие.  
  
Лишний довод за то, что и во втором случае - наречие. Но тогда идея с "простым открытием" становится несколько сомнительной. Нет?   
А второй довод, пусть и не прямой, это то, какой смысл вкладывают во фразу сейчас. Проверить просто. Попросите кого-нибудь произнести именно как крылатую фразу. На частицу не падает ударения, на наречие - обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

*Вопрос всплыл, попробую подвести итоги.*

Как я могу сейчас видеть, из авторов оставшихся вопросом никто дальше простой констатации проблемы(в лучшем случае!) дальше не пошел. Возможно, просто не поняли.

Сейчас до меня дошло, что и процитированное в одном из ответов мнение "Граммы" (нигде, кстати, в верифицируемых источниках не обнаруженное) далеко от понимания.

> В басне Крылова " А ларчик просто открывался" слово "просто", по
> общепринятому мнению, является наречием (ларчик открывался как? -
> просто, легко, без труда). Однако есть и другие мнения (на наш взгляд,
> спекулятивные, уж простите за резкость), согласно которым слово
> "просто" в этой строке является частицей в значении "всего лишь".

Плюс в том, что автор признает существование проблемы, вызываемой двусмысленностью, но и только. Приводимые варианты "открывался легко, без усилий" и "всего лишь открывался" на самом деле - это одно и тоже, ничего различного здесь нет. Не понимаю вообще, как это можно противопоставлять - да еще в таких резких выражениях.
Я реально не знаю, что хотел сказать Иван Андреевич, но выбирать-то надо не из этих вариантов.
Варианты здесь такие.

1. Ларчик **не был заперт**, то есть не имел замка (ни секретного, ни какого другого) - и открывался просто: без труда, путем поднятия крышки.
2. Замок секретный был. Но очень простой. И открывался он просто: **несложно**.

Весь текст басни говорит в пользу первого случая. Хотя "Грамма" (якобы) и назвала приверженцев этой версии "спекулянтами", но из текста трудно вывести иное.

Зачем вообще этот вопрос тут оказался?
А вот послушайте.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnS9Hwea7-Q
Читает Ильинский.
Он явно делает ударение на слове "просто" - то есть склоняется ко второй версии, "просто" здесь наречие образа действия, означающее что действия по открытию были простыми. Аналогичное исполнение яслышал и у других известных чтецов (боюсь соврать, но, кажется, даже у самого Ираклия Андроникова в его молодости).

Скажете, я сумасшедший? Ведь нас со школы учили иному?

В своё оправдание приведу еще  одно мнение. Казиник - известный человек, скрипач, хотя к литературе отношения не имеет. Но я готов подписаться под каждым его словом.

> Помните басню Крылова “Ларчик”? Про то, как некий “механики мудрец”
> взялся открыть ларец, потому как тот - был уверен дока - с секретом.
> Как ни старался мудрец, ничего не вышло, на самом же деле - помните,
> последняя строчка: “А Ларчик просто открывался”. Интересно, как вы ее
> читаете? Скорее всего, так, как учили в школе: “А Ларчик ПРОСТО
> открывался.”

А вот и неправильно, утверждает Михаил Казиник, нужно:

> “А Ларчик просто ОТКРЫВАЛСЯ!” Почему? Да потому, что если читать так, как
> вдолбили еще в детстве, остается непонятным: так КАК же открывается
> этот самый Ларчик? Получается, что старик Крылов не дописал басню. А
> вот если сделать логическое ударение на последнем слове -
> “открывался”, тогда все становится на свои места.

http://kazinik.ru/documents/arch.html

Итог. В русском языке "открыть" имеет как минимум два основных значения

> ОТКРЫТЬ, -крою, -кроешь; открытый; -крыт, -а, -о; св. что.
>
> 1. Раскрывая, распахивая двери, дверцы, крышку и т.п. какого-л. помещения, вместилища, сделать доступным их внутреннюю часть,
>    содержимое; сделать возможным доступ внутрь чего-л. О. рояль. О.
>    чемодан. О. буфет. О. кастрюлю. О. комнату. О. двери, окна, ставни. О.
>    форточку. О. дверцу автомобиля. О. калитку, ворота. О. крышку
>    (поднять, откинуть крышку). О. объятия кому-л. (развести руки,
>    намереваясь обнять кого-л.). // (чем). Отпереть, отомкнуть. О. дверь
>    ключом. О. ворота, вынув засов. Открыто! (не заперто, можно войти).
> 2. (чем). Откупорить, вскрыть, распечатать. О. штопором бутылку вина. О. ножом банку консервов. О. письмо, бандероль, пакет.

Первое - очевидное, если кому-то так понятнее, то перевод на английский - **to open**.
Второе из этих значение практически эквивалентно "отпереть", "открыть замок", **to unlock**. В хорошем английском дрерь - "open", замки, засовы и прочее невозможно открыть-"opеn", только unlock. Как видно из текста, именно в этом значении использовал слово герой-неудачник, бравшийся открыть (отпереть) ларец.

Вот и получается, что варианты от Крылова: **ларчик "просто отпирался" или "просто открывался"**. По-моему, очевидно, что первый (известный со школы, по Ильинскому и "Грамме") вариант тут не проходит.
Очень жаль, что Екатерина удалила свой ответ, оставив меня в неведении, в чем причина.

> Благодаря Вашему вопросу задумалась о функции в предложении А ЛАРЧИК
> ПРОСТО ОТКРЫВАЛСЯ слова просто. Что это: наречие - обстоятельство
> образа действия (открывался КАК? просто)или частица при глаголе
> ОТКРЫВАЛСЯ со значением "всего лишь", "лишь"? Прихожу к выводу, что,
> раз Иван Андреевич не рассказал подробно, как именно открывался
> ларчик, он имел в виду только процесс поднятия крышки путём лёгкого
> усилия руки. Значит, ПРОСТО - частица, а ларчик нужно было лишь
> открыть.

Мне он нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Из эти слов "Случается нередко нам
И труд и мудрость видеть там 
Где стоит только догадаться
За дело просто взяться" понятно,что нужно было только догадаться сразу взяться за дело и,просто ,открыть ларчик,а не трудиться (вертеть) и не думать как открыть...И такое с людьми случается нередко... "СЛУЧАЕТСЯ НЕРЕДКО " ИЛИ СЛУЧАЕТСЯ НЕ РЕДКО?"

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли ларчик открывался поднятием крышки. Самое первое, инстинктивное движение — это приподнять крышку за её края, выходящие за пределы самого корпуса.
Если же ларчик был диковинный и появилось мнение о сложном механизме и наличии якобы секретного замка — то значит, крышки с навесной защёлкой, петельками и нависающими над корпусом краями не было, а скорее всего, ларчик был гладкий со всех сторон, без выступов и крышка была "утоплена" в корпусе. То есть она, скорее всего, просто сдвигалась вбок, двигаясь по пазам, прорезанным внутри корпуса. Или же нужно было нажать на утопленную в корпусе крышку, надавливая на внутреннюю пружину, которая отщёлкивала потом крышку сама вверх, давая возможность открыть ларчик...
Всё зависит от изысканности изделия.
Замок в этих двух случаях просто некуда приспособить.

Comment: Разговор не идёт в плоскости обсуждения дизайна ларца.

Comment: дезайн ларца- это "простое" решение задачки, найденное с помощью морали, и дающее  возможность применить мудрость Крылова как  концепцию, используя её в своей жизни, для решения собственных проблем. 
 Он и оставил читателя в неведении, чтобы каждый мог найти свой "простой"вариант, интерпретируя мораль по-своему.

Comment: Теперь понятно, что «Всё зависит от изысканости изделия. Замок в этих двух случаях, просто некуда весить».

Comment: Басня — это один из видов лирико-эпического литературного жанра. Она представляет собой краткий, чаще всего стихотворный рассказ, в иносказательной форме, изображающий человеческие поступки и отношения.

Comment: Так примерно себе и представлял.

Comment: Очень много слов, не вижу ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается самой фразы- то тоже не стоит мудрить, как и с ларчиком, который Очень Просто Открывался. Необычность, не означает Сложность. Не стОит ломиться в раздвижную дверь, а надо просто отодвинуть её в сторону.

Answer (score -2):

Прочел все ответы. Для полноты картины предлагаю ещё одним вариант: басня, хоть и всеми признанна, как гениальный шедевр, таковым не является, а содержит в себе смысловую, логическую ошибку. Вполне может быть, что у Крылова были проблемы с логическим мышлением, и он этой ошибки не увидел. Это его ранняя басня, позднее он стал лучше использовать логику в баснях. Мораль: долгие споры над этой басней Крылова ни к чему: лорчик открывается просто - автор допустил смысловую, логическую ошибку.

Comment: Обсуждать наличие или отсутствие логики у классического автора тут как-то не слишком приветствуется, во всяком случае - если говорить о персоне, а не о тексте.